# Sorting documents in Lion

Tags: macos, mac, finder

I recently discovered that on Mac OS 10.7 (aka Lion) my documents on my NAS are arranged in the order "Z, Y, X, W, V, etc...". So how do I specifically change this setting of the arranging order? The bars on top (in 10.6) are now gone...

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the view properties of the Finder window. Here's how to do it using Menu commands.

- View the Finder Window as a List (View > As List).
- Set "Arrange By" to None. (View > Arrange By > None).

You should now see the Finder window property headers and then you can click on Name to sort ascending or descending.